# Pixmap Bad Component Count

Tags: java, android, libgdx

### Problem Details

I have some code that loads a `Texture` from a file, and it can't load certain files. The code:

```
// Note: this returns a valid path, and the file exists
//
FileHandle fh = Gdx.files.external(localPath);
Texture tempTexture = new Texture(fh, true);
```

For a majority of user this works. However, one user was trying to load some files, and caused the following exception that I couldn't find searching the internet:

```
Couldn't load file: Download/Resource/example.jpeg com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: Download/Resource/example.jpeg
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:142)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:112)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:108)
 at com.enplug.digitalsignage.view.TextureHelper$1.run(TextureHelper.java:39)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:493)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
 at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't load pixmap bad component count
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Gdx2DPixmap.<init>(Gdx2DPixmap.java:57)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:138)
 ... 9 more
```

Out of 11 files they uploaded: 3 of them worked and the rest failed with that exception (most users don't have this issue at all).

Looking at the files, I noticed the following different properties:

working: dpi =  72, bit depth = 24, Color representation = sRGB

failing: dpi = 300, bit depth = 32, Color representation = Uncalibrated

### My Hypothesis

I hypothesize that the issue has to with the Color representation only based on the idea that Uncalibrated just sounds negative. If not, and the issue has to do with the bit depth I might be able to fix that by adding a `Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888` to the `Texture` constructor. I'm wary of this approach because I can't afford to break the 24 bit depth images.

### The Questions

1. Does anyone know what exactly is the cause of the `java.io.IOException: couldn't load pixmap bad component count`?
2. What can I do when trying to load the files that would allow me to load all those files properly?
3. I'm able to preprocess the files if needed on a server, so which image details could cause the issue?

Comment: I am also having issues when Color representation = Uncalibrated. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, never figured this one out. We were able to ask the client to upload different images.